# how to combine two specific arrays keys and values together, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

i have two interesting arrays that im trying to combine together. Simple put:

```
$firstArr

array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(1) "1"
    [1] => string(16) "test1"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(1) "8"
    [1] => string(26) "test2"
  }
  [2] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(1) "9"
    [1] => string(23) "test3"
  }
}


$secondArr

array(3) {
  [0] => string(1) "1"
  [1] => string(1) "2"
  [2] => string(1) "3"
}
```

what i would like to get is something like this (not arrays):

```
$x = 1, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9;
$y = test1, test2, test2, test3, test3, test3;
```

basically the second array values dictates how many times the first array values are duplicated.

any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to store in `$x` and `$y`?

Comment: If `x` and `y` are not arrays, then what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$firstArr=array(array("1","test1"),array("8","test2"),array("9","test3"));


$secondArr=array("1","2","3");


$x=$y='';
foreach ($secondArr as $k=>$v){
$x.= str_repeat($firstArr[$k][0].',',$v);
$y.= str_repeat($firstArr[$k][1].',',$v);
}

echo rtrim($x,",").";\n";
echo rtrim($y,",").";";
```

OUTPUT:

1,8,8,9,9,9;
test1,test2,test2,test3,test3,test3;

working demo:

http://codepad.org/yFvWs0Rh

Comment: str_repeat() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given, but interesting approach

Comment: full stop not comma for the join, but its still broken, will fix in a bit

Comment: i can do something like:`str_repeat($firstArr[$a][0].',',$a)` and i get `string(9) "8,9,9,,,,"` and `
string(78) "test2,test3,test3,,,,"`, it doesn't give all parameters

Comment: also i get `Notice: Undefined offset: 3` for the `$x` and `$y` lines. looks like the array doesnt go to deep :)

Comment: success. wired how it was complaining about the `3rd offset` and now it doesn't. do you care to explain that for me?

Comment: i was looping array values not keys